# How to remove the static sound in an fm transmitter

Tags: capacitor, frequency, transmitter, frequency-modulation

Hi I have a school project and I used the schematics from this [website](http://makezine.com/projects/super-simple-fm-transmitter/) for our FM transmitter.

Its actually working but its hard to recognize the music being played because of the static, also does changing the electrolytic capacitor from 22µF to 1µF cause the static??

Comment: Static shouldn't harm an FM signal, as long as it appears after the modulation stage. Are you sure it isn't distortion? Changing the electro like that will only reduce audio bandwidth at the LF end.

Comment: You may well be hearing distortion rather than static.  Try lowering the volume of the music you are playing (at the input to the transmitter.)  It also might help if you could record the recieved signal and post it somewhere where we could hear it - the type of noise or distortion might give one of the more experienced people here a hint as to the cause.

Answer (score -1):

The purpose of the electrolytic capacitor is to provide a path to conduct unwanted AC to ground. There are a couple of ways to explain its purpose. Please see this article:

http://www.seattlerobotics.org/encoder/jun97/basics.html

Do you happen to have an oscilloscope at school? You could very easily see noise "riding" on your signal. (I don't think you'll need anything fancy)

Comment: Nope, we don't have an oscilloscope. Do you have any suggestions on how to remove the static and somehow increase the range of the transmitter??

Comment: The purpose of the electrolytic capacitor is to couple the audio signal from the input to the base of Q1.

Comment: So if I change my electrolytic capacitor from 1 microfarad to 22 microfarad it will remove the static somehow??

Comment: @MiguelLorenzo *Non sequitur.* See my comment under your question.

Answer (score -2):

No, changing the electrolytic capacitor does not remove the static it only changes the frequency of the fm transmitter. Static is caused by interference, installing and positioning the antenna properly may decrease the static.

Comment: C1 affects the audio, not the RF frequency.

Comment: My frequency changed by adding C1.

Comment: The RF transmission frequency is determined by L1, C3, C4. How much low-frequency AF you get is determined by C1.